# Custom Vanity views being ignored

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vanity

I'm using the vanity gem to do some AB testing, but my report is all messed up. The auto-generated css and views have a width of 40em which I would like to change. Following the [Vanity Documentation](http://vanity.labnotes.org/rails.html)
I ran

`rails g vanity:views`

which generated all the files needed, and have edited them accordingly. 
However, I am still not seeing the changes, and I can't figure out why rails is still using the defaults in the gem folder, and not those in the view.

`Started GET "/vanity" for ::1 at 2016-11-21 12:07:19 -0500
  Processing by VanityController#index as HTML
  W, [2016-11-21T12:07:19.231036 #2616]  WARN -- : No default alternative specified; choosing school_lower as default.
  AdminUser Load (1.4ms)  SELECT  "admin_users".* FROM "admin_users" WHERE "admin_users"."id" = $1  ORDER BY "admin_users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 32]]
Rendered /Users/lowellmower/.rbenv/versions/2.2.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/vanity-2.2.6/lib/vanity/templates/_ab_test.erb (754.1ms)
  Rendered /Users/lowellmower/.rbenv/versions/2.2.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/vanity-2.2.6/lib/vanity/templates/_experiment.erb (1013.5ms)`

I even explicitly added the custom_template in the configuration file

`#config/vanity.rb
Vanity.configure do |config|
  config.templates_path = 'views/vanity'
end`

Other files related to Vanity:

`#routes.rb
  get '/vanity' =>'vanity#index'
  get '/vanity/participant/:id' => 'vanity#participant'
  post '/vanity/complete'
  post '/vanity/chooses'
  post '/vanity/reset'
  post '/vanity/enable'
  post '/vanity/disable'
  post '/vanity/add_participant'
  get '/vanity/image'`

```
#app/controllers/vanity_controller.rb
class VanityController < ApplicationController
  include Vanity::Rails::Dashboard
  layout false # exclude this if you want to use your application layout

  before_action :authenticate_admin_user!

end
```

All views are in :

```
#app/views/vanity/_report.erb
```

etc
Thanks guys, any help would be grand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up being a mistake on my behalf (surprise).
Vanity doesn't take a `config/vanity.rb` by default. It all needed to go in `config/application.rb` 
Everything works fine now.

Comment: Contributor here - glad you figured it out, any way the docs/readme could have been clearer?

Comment: Ahh o don't think you can. It was an oversight on my behalf and if my memory serves the docs say to put it in application.rb and I just went ahead and put it in vanity.rb instead.